# Перестал компилироваться проект в Intelliji Idea после указания пути для smart git

Tags: java, intellij-idea, repository

После указания пути к проекту для smart git, перестал запускаться проект. Команда "Run" стала как бы недоступной. Значки классов перерисовались. В настройках по иср ничего для гита не  включено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тем не менее изменения в коде smart git видит, но отладить программу теперь не имею понятия как.

Comment: У вас явно директория сорцов в настройках проекта не указана (или указана неверно).

Comment: а какие ошибки при компиляции/сборке проекта?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Путь к сорцам явно указан. Другая проблема в том что расширение основного каталога стало .git . Поменялось оно после указания пути в SmartGit. Проблема в том что я не могу запустить программу на выполнение из иср. Кнопка "Run" стала недоступной, которая мне нужна для запуска и отладки.